# Connect a Jupyter Notebook to a running Python App

Tags: python, kivy, jupyter

I'm building a GUI Python App using Kivy. Is it possible to connect a jupyter notebook to the running python interpreter to inspect objects?

For example, if my app is producing some Pandas dataframes, is it possible to work on/manipulate/visualize instances of those objects from Jupyter Notebook?

Answer (score 1):

It was possible to use Kivy in Jupyter Notebook since Kivy version 1.3.0 using `InteractiveLauncher` (see [documentation](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.interactive.html)). However, this has been deprecated since version 1.10.0.

Comment: is there another way to use Kivy in Jupyter Notebook ?

Comment: Not that I know of, sorry.